# Collection of elements that takes unique_ptr, but stores them as shared_ptr to provide access as weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

Is the following considered a bad/good practice? Why?

```
class Scene
{
    public:
        std::weak_ptr<Node>                 AddChild(std::unique_ptr<Node> node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node>               DetachChild(std::string name);

    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>  mNodes;
};
```

The idea is to make sure that `Scene` is the only owner of its children, and force to transfer ownership when adding a `Node` to that scene. However there should be a way for clients to have access to Nodes stored inside the Scene (without constantly looking up it by name/id).

Typical example would be something like:

1. You have an UI window that you create (Scene)
2. You add several text labels to it (Nodes)
3. You want to save pointers to those labels so that later you could modify the text.

Alternative would be also to add using `unique_ptr` but return `raw pointer`, however the text could be updated in different classes and there should always be a check that the label exists (e.g. there can be a running `Tween` function that updates text in a loop which you trigger in "Fire and forget" mode and just want to make sure it won't access dangling pointer(think of `cocos2d` actions) Even if checking just means just catching and assert).

Comment: Guess what happens if I add a pointer, then copy the shared_ptr, then detach it, then delete my copied shared_ptr

Comment: How would you copy `shared_ptr`? Clients only get access to `shared_ptr` for reference or can "take away" the node completely by Detaching.

Comment: `AddChild(...).lock()` returns a `shared_ptr<Node>`.

Comment: `auto shared = scene.AddChild( std::make_unique<Node>() ).lock();`

Comment: Well, of course you can do that. You could also save raw pointer before passing it to AddChild. But why would you want to do that? I'm trying to defend against Murphy not Machiavelli :)

Comment: @KirillMuzykov What's the point of using shared_ptr and weak_ptr then? Is it so clients can know when the node was removed?

Comment: @immibis Yes. Basically I need `unique_ptr` that can return a pointer that will become null as soon as the original `unique_ptr` gets destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not possible due to the nature of `shared_ptr`. While `unique_ptr` allows you to extract the pointer without deleting it, `shared_ptr` does not.

What you want is also not good practice, due to threading. Even if you implement your own smart pointer that does exactly what you want, how do you use it? It would be possible for a user to lock one of those handles, then in another thread you convert your internal smart pointer to a `unique_ptr`. How does that work? What you have is two pieces of code both conceptually owning the object, but only one of them controls its lifetime.

Unless you forbid threading, that is very much in Murphy's realm.

Things like this are precisely why `shared_ptr` cannot abandon its ownership of the pointer.

> Basically I need `unique_ptr` that can return a pointer that will become null as soon as the original `unique_ptr` gets destroyed.

This is precisely why `weak_ptr` does not provide direct access to the internal pointer. You have to *lock* it, which guarantees that you can access the memory for as long as you keep that `shared_ptr` around.

This coding pattern prevents the exact kind of data races that your idea will create.

`shared_ptr` was designed by some very smart people working over a long period of time. Ignore its wisdom at your own peril.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I forgot to mention about single-threaded environment, but I didn't know that there is no `shared_ptr::release` (even though one could probably implement it with custom deleter). However, I want to avoid situation when `Node` lives outside the `Scene` and with `shared_ptr` it is very easy to do so.